# How to Trap Tomcat's Terminate in Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, application-shutdown

When I terminate my Java Application in Eclipse, it doesn't trigger the destroy() function but the application gets terminated.

Where and how can I capture Tomcat's shutdown (or Terminate button in Eclipse) in Java so that I could run the cleaning operations like closing threads etc.

Comment: Instead of eclipse try using tomcat directly from a command line and check the behaviour when you terminate Tomcat either with Ctl+c or shutdown.bat/sh. Far as I recollect, Tomcat calls the destry() method of servlets during context destroyed event

Comment: Which `destroy` method are you talking about? How do you know it's not being called?